# Notepad++ find and replace with word containing first word?

Tags: replace, merge

I have in one file words in 2 columns and 2 word in row represent interaction.

```
A0AV96  P25515      
A6H8V1  A4D1U5      
A8YXX4  A6NCZ6      
B0ZBE0  A8BBF9      
B3KWQ6  B3KRK5      
B4E398  A4D1N9      
B6ZGU1  B3KPR3
```

In second file i have litle bit more information about interactors like this. Here information in every row is extendend info about word from above file.

```
A0AV96 RBM47_HUMAN 
P25515 E2F8_HUMAN 
A0JLT2 MED19_HUMAN 
A1ZBR5 AKTP2_DROME 
A1ZBT5 MED8_DROME 
A2A3L6 TTC24_HUMAN
```

What i need is some way to merge or find and replace words from this two files that i get from this

```
A0AV96  P25515
```

to this

```
A0AV96 RBM47_HUMAN P25515 E2F8_HUMAN
```

Comment: I think you need to write some code to accomplish this.  Text editors are not designed to do this kind of merging.

Comment: Yes, i fear so. Problem is i am not so good in that :). Any help or advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Spend a few hours learning python (or C#, Java, Haskell, whatever). When you've figured out reading text files, splitting strings, looping through lists, you should be able to make a good attempt. If you get stuck on an error or something, ask a new question about it.

Comment: Do u know is there any software solution that can help me for now? thanks.

Comment: Your example looks a lot like a relational database. You could quite simply import the data into Microsoft Access and create queries to provide the data in the format you require, perhaps with some simple text post-processing. Just a thought if you don't want to do any actual programming.

Answer (score 0):

For now i find solution without need for programing. There is at least 2 ways to do this. First i separate each column in single column line list file, as strand of DNA. After that i use 'Find and Replace Multiple Items At Once Software' to change this line in way i need. And after that i merge 2 lines again i 2 columns structure. Only problem is u must align properly your one column from 2 column file and column from file with additional information.